# Crossplattform way to check active directory in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

I want to read data from an Active Directory within an ASP.NET Core 6 app. I know how this can be achieved with a DirectorySearcher:

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry(GlobalConfig.Configuration.LDAP, Input.Username, Input.Password);

try
{
    var _object = entry.NativeObject;
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    searcher.Filter = $"(SAMAccountName={Input.Username})";
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeid");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephonenumber");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
catch(Excepetion ex)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, this solution does only work when we host the app within a windows environment. Is there any way to check this data with a cross plattform approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) package and specifically the [`LdapConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class.

**Example:**

```cs
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
...

try
{
    using var connection = new LdapConnection("{server}");

    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Input.Username, Input.Password, "{domain}");
    connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
    connection.Bind(networkCredential);

    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
        "{distinguishedName}",
        $"(SAMAccountName={Input.Username})",
        SearchScope.OneLevel,
        new string[]
        {
            "cn",
            "memberOf",
            "employeeid",
            "telephonenumber",
            "displayName",
            "mail"
        });

    SearchResponse directoryResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

    SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry = directoryResponse.Entries[0];
    // ...
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{
    // ...
}
```

Modify connection and search options accordingly. You can find documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dacx/how-to-enumerate-active-directory-definitions-for-user-and-device-claims-and-resource-properties). You might get warning for `LdapSessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer` that it is only supported on Windows but this is a false warning that you can [ignore](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62462).

Comment: This seems a good solution. I can't figure out what I should insert for distinguishedName. Can you provide me an example for this?

Comment: Nevermind. I'll need to put the DC entries there.

Comment: Hi again! I was able to read almost every property I need from this approach. However I cannot figure out how to get the formatted objectGUID. Do you know how this can be achived?

Comment: Did you try to add objectGUID to the attribute array?

Comment: Yes, I have it in the attribute array. But I cannot convert it to a Guid object.

Comment: Try this: `var objectGUID = new Guid((byte[])searchResultEntry.Attributes["objectGUID"][0]);`